# ColdFusion 8 Application Server / Apache2.2 on Windows 7

Tags: coldfusion

I have set up Eclipse Indigo to do line debugging with CFEclipse over port 80 (which I also changed in CF Admin to match).  Now when I go to services and restart the ColdFusion 8 service it crashed.

I did some research and found out it was because port 80 is being used by Apache 2.2.  So I stopped the Apache2.2 service and started the ColdFusion 8 service so that I could go into CF Admin and change the port to something else.  The problem is that CF Admin will not load up anymore, even though the ColdFusion 8 service is running.

Anyone know what I need to do to get CF Admin to work so that I can go in and change the port so that this won't happen again?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the cfusion9/lib directory (or wherever your lib is for your instance) for the neo-debug.xml file. Find the value for "LINE_DEBUGGER_ENABLED" and set the boolean there to false. Stop CF, start Apache, start CF - see if your admin will load.

first thing to do once you are in there is pick a different port :)

another approach would be to edit your httpd.conf file and change the port that Apache is listening. Look for "*:80" in there somewhere... (I think that's right). change it to.. 8080 say - and restart Apache.